# Tableau find count of dimension for each of other dimension

Tags: tableau-api, dimension

I have 3 columns in my data "Date", CustomerID and Action Type (There are 10 different types of Action type like item hover, product click etc)
I want to eliminate those customers who has interactions of less that 20.
For example, for a customer ID say 10, if the count of all the action type against this customer is less than 20 I want to eliminate that customer. I want to do this for each ween and create a line graph may be.

Somebody please help, Although I am trying to do this in tableau but excel and access solutions are welcomed too. I have tried everything I could but still couldn't do it. My calculated field only works if I use customer Id along wth count which gives me a table that I dont want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Action Type cannot be null, put CustomerID on the filter shelf, select the "Use All" radio button at the top of the filter panel, switch to the Condition tab, Choose "By Field", and require the SUM of the Number of Records to be >= 20

If Action Type can be null, do the same but use COUNT of Action Type instead of SUM of Number Of Records.

Filters have multiple tabs. You can see a summary of how the filter is defined at the bottom of the General tab.